# Problem in fetching image from database

Tags: android

Friend's,
  I stored image url has a byte array in database has blob type and at time of fetching this image i'm getting nullpointer exception.how can i fix this problem,here the code for fetching data from db...
  String bb = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(JR_Constants.IMAGE_97));
               Log.v(TAG,bb);
                 Bitmap theImage = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bb, 0, bb.length);
                 myImage.setImageBitmap(theImage);
what i'm doing mistake here.

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert the String to a ByteArray. Basically just do `bb.getBytes()` instead of passing `bb`

```
String bb = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(JR_Constants.IMAGE_97));
Log.v(TAG,bb);
Bitmap theImage = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bb.getBytes(), 0, bb.length());
myImage.setImageBitmap(theImage);
```

I just want to note that `bb.length` should be `bb.length()`

Comment: Actually you are wrong about length. bb.length is the correct spelling.

Comment: bb is of type String not an array, so it's length() method.